# How can I dual boot with NVME SSD?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, gparted, nvme

I need to dual boot Windows and Linux Mint on one SSD. I've mint on my system already

So I loaded with a LIVE CD on Ubunutu, then I run a Gparted but my SSD have a little key icon next to the name. My SSD device name is `nvme0n1p2` and my USB device is `sda1` for some reason.

In resize / move my drive looks filled, although this is actually not the case. How can I free up space? I'm a novice in this area.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the instruction for installing windows after you've installed Linux:

- Make space for Windows
- Install Windows
- Mount the /boot directory or partition
- Install the bootloader (GRUB)

[How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

- First of all install windows on your SSD.
- Leave enough free space (e.g. use 50% of disk space for each) for your ubuntu/Mint Linux during the windows installation.
- After windows installation is finished , install Ubuntu/Mint on the free space of your SSD.
- During boot process you can choose to boot Ubuntu/Mint (default) or windows.

Comment: I have linux already, Mint, sorry I didn't write it, I thought it would be clear from the context, can i leave it somehow?

Comment: It's also possible that you install windows alongside your Linux Mint. The problem is that windows will overwrite the MBR ( Linux Mint) in your SSD. However, it is not easy for Linux beginners to do this.
I suggest backing up your data from SSD and installing windows first and then Linux Mint, as I have described above.

Comment: Yes, i tried to do this but on a setup part of Windows it's says that i have no drivers for USB or SSD, idk what to do. To be honest, I am quite embarssing.